Nepenthes leaves browning?
I got my nepenthes about a month ago and it was doing great and now all of a sudden brown spots are appearing everywhere and getting bigger by the day please help

The pink tinge is from a growing light, correct? What are your humidity levels?

Yes it is and I live in Tennessee and I’m in my basement so it’s super humid in here and I also have a fan about 6-10 feet away on high for air circulation idk if it’s overwatering or under or to much light or to little I noticed the spots so I thought it was sun burn so I moved it up more to where it wasn’t direct and then that’s when they just started growing way more so I put it back under the light and it’s potted in LFS and perlite mix but the spots feel kinda mushy so maybe it’s holding to much water? But the top is dry but the bottom is damp but I’m scared to water tho

@Stephie the pitcher themselves seem okay and producing a little liquid but idk if those will get same way

How can you overwater a bog plant? Underwatering can brown the edges from root stress.

What is the species? Did you check for root rot?

@YosefBaskin Are all Nepenthes considered "bog plants"? I think it depends on species. I live in Borneo, and I observe plenty of wild Nepenthes outside peat swamps. For example, Nepenthes gracilis seems to be able to grow in very sandy soil.

The only reason I’m worried about overwatering is because I live in a basement and it’s very humid/ moist down here and I just tried to bottom water it with distilled water but it didn’t take any so that worried me more and I don’t know what species it is I emailed the nursery I got it from but they said they didn’t know either that they just come to them as nepenthes and I may need to check for root rot if it is that then it maybe in a little big of a pot so I might just put it in a smaller pot and hope for the best

@lesleejade. Does your plant have pitchers? If so, could you post some pictures of the pitchers for the purpose of species identification?

If you can't move it into actual daylight(in order to eliminate the possibility of wrong light cycle or spectrum) You might spray some contact fungicide and hope for the best but be prepared for the worst.

@Vorac the only reason I don’t want to move it upstairs is because people will mess with it and I’m just not trying to come home to a pitcher missing or something or just downright gone (trust me it happened before had a plant sitting out and the next morning the plant was literally gone but the pot and soil somehow still in the pot..?) I think I might just let it be and if it hates me then I guess it just doesn’t like its home

And if anything it might be a fungal issue because it is so humid/ moist in here but that’s why I have a fan because there is literally no air circulation down here so I have that about 6-10 feet away on high

A fan does not alter the humidity of air. What it does is make more air get in contact with the plant.
